# Designing a stat block for a 5e Hieracosphinx

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, monster-design

The Hieracosphinx is a lesser Sphinx that does not have an official stat block for 5e, as via Christopher Perkins' [Twitter](https://twitter.com/chrisperkinsdnd/status/701808110994747392). However, I would like to use this monster in a desert setting with Level 6 characters, for which the more powerful [Gynosphinx](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Gynosphinx#content) (CR 11) and [Androsphinx](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Androsphinx#content) (CR 17) are out of question for being too powerful and not evil. In 3e, which I'm not at all familiar with, the Hieracosphinx had a CR of 5 apparently, see [here](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/magical-beasts/sphinx/hieracosphinx), but I have no idea if I could translate the stats 1 to 1 into 5.

Another idea that I had was scaling up a [Griffon](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Griffon#content) (CR 2), giving it the Gynosphinx's Claw Multiattack, a bit more HP and a few spells from the spell list.

So, how do I make a Hieracosphinx for this edition?  I have never designed a monster from scratch before, only adding or subtracting 1 or 2 things from existing monsters sometimes.

Comment: Have you read the DMG chapter on designing monsters? Is there anything missing that you need to know, specifically?

Comment: You mention a CR 5 monster from the previous edition, and your players are level 6.  What CR are you aiming for?  5, 6, 7, 8?

Comment: I would like to avoid the "1 powerful monster nova'd by players in the first round" scenario, so rather lower CR (5), but more than 1 sphinx, maybe 2 or 3.

My first attempt would have been: large monstrosity, chaotic evil, AC 15, 135 HP, +6 to attack, Claw Multiattack with 2d8+4 slashing damage, spells from the Gynosphinx up to Level 3, with 4/3/2 slots for Level 1/2/3 spells, respectively. But the spells feel kinda "wrong" to me, as they're all support or CC type spells, while the Androsphinx's spells are spells with a "lawful good" vibe (sacred flame, zone of truth etc.).

Comment: Somewhat related: [convert 3.5 enemies to 5e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/84081/how-can-i-convert-enemies-from-dd-3-5e-to-5e)

Comment: For what it's worth, the Hieracosphinx you linked to is from Pathfinder (1e) which while related to 3e, isn't the same.

Comment: Since you already have an idea, you might want to ask in a similar manner to [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/140233/52137). The reasoning in the (good) answers should give you a good guideline to make adjustments. If not, try prompting for it in comments or join us in [chat].